# Extracting the coefficients of a polynomial from a lambda in Python

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalue

I'm working on some linear algebra and using `numpy` for reference. I use `lambda k:  numpy.linalg.det(A - k*I)` to compute the characteristic polynomial of a matrix `A`.

That works wonderfully, and the next step would be to calculate the roots of that polynomial which represents the eigenvalues of the matrix, using `numpy.roots`, the problem being that `numpy.roots` takes a polynomial coefficients as argument.

Is there any way to extract the coefficients from the `lambda k`?

(I am aware of the existence of `numpy.linalg.eigvals` but I would rather not use it.)

Comment: its certainly possible to do it numerically. have a look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html for an overview

Comment: Numpy and scipy provides eig and svd method. It would help you to determine eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer thanks to [How to find coefficients of polynomial equation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43566648/how-to-find-coefficients-of-polynomial-equation)

```
# yields the coefficients from highest to lowest degree
def extract_coefficients(p, degree):
    n = degree + 1
    sample_x = [ x for x in range(n) ]
    sample_y = [ p(x) for x in sample_x ]
    A = [ [ 0 for _ in range(n) ] for _ in range(n) ]
    for line in range(n):   
        for column in range(n):
            A[line][column] = sample_x[line] ** column
    c = numpy.linalg.solve(A, sample_y)
    return c[::-1]
```

Running `extract_coefficients(lambda x: 2*x**2 - 2*x + 1, 2)` yields the correct result `[ 2. -2.  1.]`.
Many thanks to the people who originally responded!
Edit:
The code can be compressed further if you don't care about readability as such:

```
# yields the coefficients from highest to lowest degree
def extract_coefficients(p, d):
    return (numpy.linalg.solve([[[x for x in range(d+1)][line] ** column for column in range(d+1)] for line in range(d+1)], [p(x) for x in [x for x in range(d+1)]]))[::-1]
```