# How to set up and solve for equations in python?

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I'm looking to run this code that enables to solve for the unknowns `c_10` and `c_01` from just plotting the graph.

Some background on the equation is using Mooney-Rivlin model (1940) with `c_10[(2*λ+λ**2)-3]+c_01[(λ**-2+2*λ)-3]`.

Some of the unknowns `I_1` and `I_2` are defined below in the code. `P1` (or known as `P`) and `lambda` are data pre-defined in numerical terms in the table below (sheet [ExperimentData of experimental_data1.xlsx](https://entuedu-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/echang009_e_ntu_edu_sg/EUkAPrZ8pMlFsMInxpCPkpEBcEisrQIljkCsZU4H9EU2IA?e=nZB1iX)):

```
λ       P
1.00    0.00
1.01    0.03
1.12    0.14
1.24    0.23
1.39    0.32
1.61    0.41
1.89    0.50
2.17    0.58
2.42    0.67
3.01    0.85
3.58    1.04
4.03    1.21
4.76    1.58
5.36    1.94
5.76    2.29
6.16    2.67
6.40    3.02
6.62    3.39
6.87    3.75
7.05    4.12
7.16    4.47
7.27    4.85
7.43    5.21
7.50    5.57
7.61    6.30
```

Below is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import warnings

from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution

# Generic Mooney-Rivlin Equation
# bounds on parameters are set in
# generate_Initial_Parameters() below
def generic_equation(c_10, c_01, λ, P):
    P = c_10[(2 * λ + λ ** 2) - 3] + c_01[(λ ** -2 + 2 * λ) - 3]
    return (P)

# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
# bounds on parameters are set in generate_Initial_Parameters() below
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    return np.sum((yData - generic_equation(xData, *parameterTuple)) ** 2)

def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    maxY = max(yData)
    minY = min(yData)

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([0.0, 1.0*1000000.0]) # parameter bounds for c_10
    parameterBounds.append([0.0, 1.0*1000000.0]) # parameter bounds for c_01
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # parameter bounds for λ
    parameterBounds.append([minY, maxY]) # parameter bounds for P

# "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
return result.x


# load the test data from Experimental dataset
data = pd.read_excel('experimental_data1.xlsx', sheet_name='ExperimentData')
xData = data['λ'].values
yData = data['P'].values


# generate initial parameter values
initialParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(generic_equation, xData, yData, initialParameters)

# create values for display of fitted peak function
c_10, c_01, λ, P = fittedParameters
y_fit = generic_equation(xData, c_10, c_01, λ, P)

plt.plot(xData, yData) # plot the raw data
plt.plot(xData, y_fit) # plot the equation using the fitted parameters
plt.show()

print(fittedParameters)
```

When I run it, this error is produced:

> RuntimeError: The map-like callable must be of the form f(func, iterable), returning a sequence of numbers the same length as 'iterable'

This is the original code found from [here](https://bitbucket.org/zunzuncode/ramanspectroscopyfit/src/master/RamanSpectroscopyFit.py).

Comment: Not related but `parameterBounds.append([0.0, 1.0*1000000.0])` does not make sense since `1.0*1000000.0` is the same as `1000000.0`.

Comment: *"Some background on the equation is using Mooney-Rivlin model (1940) with `c_10[(2*λ+λ**2)-3]+c_01[(λ**-2+2*λ)-3]`."* Yes, but `c_10[(2*λ+λ**2)-3]+c_01[(λ**-2+2*λ)-3]` is a number, not an equation. Perhaps you meant `c_10[(2*λ+λ**2)-3]+c_01[(λ**-2+2*λ)-3] == P`?

Comment: Where in the code do you get that error?

Comment: *"Some of the unknowns I_1 and I_2 are defined below in the code. "* What are I_1 and I_2? What have they got to do with anything? You only mentioned c_10, c_01, lambda and P.

Comment: Also please make sure that the code you included in your question is a [mre]. In particular, please include all relevant `import`. I can guess that I need to add `import pandas as pd` to make `pd.read_excel` work, but do I also have to guess `from scipy.optimize import curve_fit`?

Comment: Looks like you are passing incorrect arguments to the `differential_evolution` call. https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/8a64c938ddf1ae4c02a08d2c5e38daeb8d061d38/scipy/optimize/_differentialevolution.py#L974

Comment: @accdias Hi there, the c_10 and c_01 values are in x10^6 format ranging from 0 to 1!

Comment: @JeffUK I got that in line 11 where: 
**return np.sum((yData - generic_equation(xData, *parameterTuple)) ** 2)**

Error given was 
_TypeError: generic_equation() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are simply trying to use linear regression to find the best values of `c_10` and `c_01` to best fit your `λ` and `P` data.

So I suggest using [`LinearRegression` from scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html).

I copied your `λ` and `P` data into a csv file named 'curvefitdata.csv'.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_csv('curvefitdata.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
y = df['P']
X = [[(2*λ+λ**2)-3, (λ**-2+2*λ)-3] for λ in df['λ']]

reg = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False).fit(X, y)
c_10, c_01 = reg.coef_

print(c_10, c_01)
# 0.16781162162572094 -0.5190608351956174
```

Testing:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

λ = df['λ']
z = reg.predict(X)
plt.plot(λ, y, label='data')
plt.plot(λ, z, label='best fit')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('λ')
plt.ylabel('P')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Stef, this is a good start. Thanks for this! However, can I check that there is any way that other forms of regressions can be used instead of linear regression such as Random Forest to obtain coef?

Comment: @NotaPythonGeek Yes, I guess.

Comment: Let's say there are multiples in front of the c_10 or c_01 coefficients, how do i go about doing it? Also with c_10 and c_01 multiplying each other as shown at the start of the equation below:
`2*c_10*c_01*[(2*λ+λ**2)-3]+c_01[(λ**-2+2*λ)-3]`

Comment: If you have a term like `2 * c_10 * ((2*λ+λ**2)-3)`, that's not a problem at all. Just factor the `c_10` out: `c_10 * (2 * ((2*λ+λ**2)-3))`. However if you have `c_10 * c_10` somewhere, then this becomes quadratic regression, instead of linear regression.

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, when I tried the suggestion above, the c_01 and c_10 values are sub it back into the equation and produces this graph [https://entuedu-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/echang009_e_ntu_edu_sg/EZQdLO9x7tpEog3m7r0rMDsBvI7XVKM5dTAUbPhw3vk5MA?e=kgRi1c]

The supposedly c_10 (around 0.18 ~ 0.23) and c_01 (-0.005 ~ -0.05)

Am i missing something that the coefs are not meant to be taken as it is? Like here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64849771/extracting-the-coefficients-of-a-polynomial-from-a-lambda-in-python]